# Is there a better way to create programmatic post pages?

Tags: gatsby

I'm using Gatsby v3 and using gatsby-source-wordpress. Is there a better way to create programmatic post pages?

my {wpPost.uri}.js

```js
imports....

const Wrapper = styled.div`
  max-width: 1180px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
`
const ContentWrapper = styled.div`
  display: block;

  h1 {
    font-size: var(--fontSuperBig);
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: none;
  }
  @media (min-width: 992px) {
    display: flex;
  }
`
const PosContent = styled.article`
  margin: 20px;
`

const PostTemplate = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Seo title={data.post.title} description={data.post.excerpt} />
      <Wrapper>
        <BreadCrumb
          parent={{
            uri: '/blog/todos-os-posts',
            title: 'Blog'
          }}
        />
        <ContentWrapper>
          <PostSidebar
            date={data.post.date}
            author={data.post.author.node.name}
            categories={data.post.categories.nodes}
          />
          <PosContent>
            <h1 dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: data.post.title }} />
            <article dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: data.post.content }} />
          </PosContent>
        </ContentWrapper>
      </Wrapper>
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

My graphql to grab data:

```js
export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query($id: String!) {
    post: wpPost(id: { eq: $id }) {
      title
      content
      excerpt
      author {
        node {
          name
        }
      }
      date(formatString: "DD, MMMM, YYYY", locale: "pt")
      categories {
        nodes {
          id
          name
          uri
          slug
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

If you share the post on any social network, the tag `p` appears
[image]

And the images are not optimized for webp and do not respect the @media large container
[image]

In the rest of the site all images work perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And the images are not optimized for webp and do not respect the
> @media large container

According to [this recent GitHub thread](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-source-wordpress-experimental/issues/337), `gatsby-source-wordpress` plugin has fixed the image treatment in version `5.0.0`. It seems that some image nodes were leaking of Gatsby's treatment and hence, the images were not correctly parsed and applied the proper transformations.

To upgrade it, just run:

```
npm install gatsby-source-wordpress@5.0.0 // or yarn add gatsby-source-wordpress@5.0.0
```